# Are these answers regarding focus and directrix correct?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

**1. Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**

$y = 2x^2$

$(y-0) = 2(x-0)^2$

$(x-0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(y-0)$

$4p = \frac{1}{2} \implies p = \frac{1}{8}$

**V:$(0,0)$
F: $(0,\frac{1}{8})$ 
D: $y = -\frac{1}{8}$**

**2. Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**
$$y = -2018x^2$$

$(x-0)^2 = -\frac{1}{2018}(y-0)$

$4p = -\frac{1}{2018} \implies p = -\frac{1}{8072}$

**V: $(0,0)$
F: $(0,-\frac{1}{8072})$
D: $y = \frac{1}{8072}$**

**3. Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**

$(y-2)^2 = 8(x+5)$

$4p = 8 \implies p = 2$

**V: $(-5,2)$
F: $(-3,2)$
D: $x= -7$**

**4. Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**

$(y+6)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(x-1)$

$4p = \frac{1}{2} \implies p = \frac{1}{8}$

**V:$(1,-6)$
F:$(\frac{9}{8},-6)$
D:$x = \frac{7}{8}$**

**5. Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**

$y = 2x^2+5x-7$

$x^2+\frac{5}{2}x-\frac{7}{2} = \frac{y}{2}$

$x^2+\frac{5}{2}x = \frac{y}{2} +\frac{7}{2}$

$x^2+\frac{5}{2}x +\frac{25}{16}= \frac{y}{2} +\frac{7}{2}+\frac{25}{16}$

$(x+\frac{5}{4})^2 = \frac{81}{16}+\frac{y}{2}$

$(x+\frac{5}{4})^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{81}{8}+y)$

$4p = \frac{1}{2} \implies p = \frac{1}{8}$

**V:$(-\frac{5}{2}, -\frac{81}{8})$
F:$(-\frac{5}{2}, -\frac{80}{8})$
D:$y = -\frac{82}{8}$**

**6.  Find the vertex, focus and directrix for the parabola given by**

$y = -\frac{x^2}{4} - 2x +8$

$-4y = x^2 +8x -32$

$x^2 +8x +16 = 16+32+(-4y)$

$(x+4)^2 = 48 - 4y$

$(x+4)^2 = 4(12 - y)$

$(x+4)^2 = -4(y-12)$
$4p = -4 \implies p= -1$

**V:$(-4,12)$
F:$(-4,11)$
D:$y = 13$**

**7. Find the equation of the parabola which passes through the point $(8,12)$ with a vertex of $(4,-2)$**

This one I'm a little confused about, aren't there multiple parabolas which could could through this point and have this vertex? I'm just going to assume it's squared in the x term, so:

$(x-4)^2 = 4p(y+2)$

$(8-4)^2 = 4p(12+2)$

$16 = 4p(14)$

$\frac{16}{14} = 4p \implies p = \frac{4}{14}$

**The equation is** $(x-4)^2 = \frac{16}{14} (y+2)$

**8. Explain, with words, how the distance between the vertex and focus of a
parabola affects the steepness of the parabola**

As the distance between the focus and directrix increases, $|p|$ decreases which means the parabola widens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the other answers are correct, equation of directrix is wrong in the fourth question (it should be $\frac{7}{8}$), the final answer written in the seventh question is wrong $\Big($putting value of 4p the final equation becomes $(x-4)^2 = \frac{16}{14}(y+2)\Big)$ and in the eighth question, we know that the distance between focus and directrix is 2|p|, therefore, as the distance increases, |p| increases.

Hope it is helpful:)

Comment: thank you! can you explain how my answer for p is wrong in the 7th question?

Comment: Your answer for p is correct, but in the original equation you have to replace the value of 4p and not p only

Comment: also im confused about your last statement regarding question 8. i thought that as the distance ebtween focus and directrix increases, that |p| decreases

Comment: ohh i understand my issue for question 7, thank you

Comment: what is the distance between focus and directrix?

Comment: should be 2|p| right?

Comment: If 2|p| increases, how can |p| decrease?

Comment: oh right. but then as |p| increases i.e. the distance between the vertex and focus increases, then how does that affect the steepness of the parabola

Comment: The parabola widens on increasing this distance.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem.